# Logic behind writing custom planned contrasts for a triple interaction

Tags: interaction, contrasts, lsmeans, apriori

I have a model with a triple interaction involving two factors and one continuous variable.

Replicable example:

```r
# %%%
set.seed(1234)

make_times <- function(n, n_per_group) {
  vector <- c()
  for (i in 1:n) {
    one_increment_sequence <- seq(0, to = n_per_group - 1)
    increment_vecor <- c(0, c(runif(n_per_group - 1, 0, 1)))
    vector <- c(vector, one_increment_sequence + increment_vecor)
  }
  return(vector)
}

# Define the dataset
dataset <- data.frame(
  Outcome = rnorm(60),
  Group = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 20),
  Sex = rep(c("M", "F"), each = 15, times = 4),
  TimeFromBaseline = make_times(20, 3), # Continuous
  Extra = sample(c("Foo", "Bar"), 60, replace = TRUE) # Fixed Covariate
)
dataset$Group <- factor(dataset$Group, levels = c("A", "B", "C", "D"))
dataset$Sex <- factor(dataset$Sex, levels = c("M", "F"))
dataset$Extra <- factor(dataset$Extra, levels = c("Foo", "Bar"))
str(dataset)

# Fit a model
model <- lm(Outcome ~ Sex * Group * TimeFromBaseline + Extra, data = dataset)
summary(model)

# Plot the model
sjPlot::plot_model(model, type = "pred", terms = c("TimeFromBaseline", "Group", "Sex"))
```

[image]

There are 13 coefficients in the model. My goal is to define length-13 contrast vectors that test certain hypotheses. [This is because I will be conducting brain voxelwise analysis and the software requires manually specifying planned contrasts a priori](https://fsl.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsl/fslwiki/GLM#ANOVA:_2-groups.2C_2-levels_per_subject_.282-way_Mixed_Effect_ANOVA.29)

I have a basic understanding of what each coefficient represents in treatment encoding scheme R uses by default:

- Beta0 is the mean of the reference level (in this case Group A, Male, at the intercept)
- Beta1 is would be the increment from the base reference level, changing Male -> Female
- etc.

So, presumably, the contrast vector testing whether a male from Group A has a non-zero outcome at time zero (intercept) would be:

`c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)`

Or the contrast vector describing the slope of a female from Group B would be

`c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0.04, 0, 1, 0, -1.35, -0.36, 0, 1.86, 0)`

Right?

If so, where it gets difficult for me is understanding how to construct hypothesis-testing contrast matrices.

For example, what contrast matrix here (presumably with 13 columns) would test the hypothesis: the triple interaction is greater than zero

^ Can anyone give a rundown of how such a contrast matrix would be constructed?

The contrasts provided to packages like `emmeans` or `lsmeans` or `multcomp` are short vectors that specifically target what is provided to their library-focus object like `emmGrid`. That's not what I'm looking for.

P.S If there is an R library that can provide these "full" or "a priori" contrast matrices from a model like how `model.matrix` provides a design matrix, that would make my day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I think you are demonstrating, trying to interpret coefficients becomes increasingly difficult as the number of factors increases. However, you can get the needed weights easily if you can get **emmeans** to do the contrasts you want.

Suppose, for example, you want Dunnett-style comparisons of `Group` means for various combinations of `Sex` and `TimeFromBaseline`. To do this in `emmeans`, you'd code:

```
> emm <- emmeans(model, ~ Group | Sex * TimeFromBaseline, at = list(TimeFromBaseline = 0:3))
> con <- contrast(emm, "dunnett")
```

This will create 2 x 4 = 8 sets of 2 contrasts; here are the first few:

```
> head(con)
 contrast Sex TimeFromBaseline estimate    SE  df t.ratio p.value
 B - A    M                  0    0.542 0.388 107   1.396  0.5307
 C - A    M                  0    1.061 0.646 107   1.641  0.3803
 B - A    F                  0   -1.031 0.536 107  -1.924  0.2362
 C - A    F                  0   -0.920 0.493 107  -1.865  0.2628
 B - A    M                  1   -0.166 0.261 107  -0.637  0.9313
 C - A    M                  1    0.329 0.396 107   0.832  0.8589
```

`con` is an object of class `emmGrid` and it has everything it needs to estimate these contrasts - the regression coefficients, covariances, *and the linear functions of those coefficients*. The latter is what you need, and they are stored in the `linfct` slot. So to see them, just look at that slot:

```
> head(con@linfct)
     (Intercept) SexF GroupB GroupC TimeFromBaseline ExtraBar SexF:GroupB SexF:GroupC
[1,]           0    0      1      0                0        0           0           0
[2,]           0    0      0      1                0        0           0           0
[3,]           0    0      1      0                0        0           1           0
[4,]           0    0      0      1                0        0           0           1
[5,]           0    0      1      0                0        0           0           0
[6,]           0    0      0      1                0        0           0           0
     SexF:TimeFromBaseline GroupB:TimeFromBaseline GroupC:TimeFromBaseline
[1,]                     0                       0                       0
[2,]                     0                       0                       0
[3,]                     0                       0                       0
[4,]                     0                       0                       0
[5,]                     0                       1                       0
[6,]                     0                       0                       1
     SexF:GroupB:TimeFromBaseline SexF:GroupC:TimeFromBaseline
[1,]                            0                            0
[2,]                            0                            0
[3,]                            0                            0
[4,]                            0                            0
[5,]                            0                            0
[6,]                            0                            0
```

Each row of this matrix comprises the 13 weights needed to estimate the corresponding contrast.

#### For the 3-way interaction itself

For this, we need an *interaction* contrast. This entails setting up two different values of each covariate (`timeFromBaseline` in this case); then the `"consec"` contrasts avoid any linear dependence among the contrasts:

```
> emm2 = emmeans(model, ~ Group * Sex * TimeFromBaseline, cov.reduce = range)

> (con2 <- contrast(emm2, interaction = "consec"))
 Group_consec Sex_consec TimeFromBaseline_consec estimate   SE  df t.ratio p.value
 B - A        F - M      2.99874080810696 - 0       3.377 1.18 107   2.866  0.0050
 C - B        F - M      2.99874080810696 - 0      -0.278 1.24 107  -0.224  0.8233

Results are averaged over the levels of: Extra 

> con2@linfct
     (Intercept) SexF GroupB GroupC TimeFromBaseline ExtraBar SexF:GroupB SexF:GroupC
[1,]           0    0      0      0                0        0           0           0
[2,]           0    0      0      0                0        0           0           0
     SexF:TimeFromBaseline GroupB:TimeFromBaseline GroupC:TimeFromBaseline
[1,]                     0                       0                       0
[2,]                     0                       0                       0
     SexF:GroupB:TimeFromBaseline SexF:GroupC:TimeFromBaseline
[1,]                     2.998741                     0.000000
[2,]                    -2.998741                     2.998741
```

These two contrasts define the 2 d.f. for the 3-way interaction. [They'd have come out as less messy if we had specified `at = list(TimeAfterBaseline = c(0,3))` instead of `cov.reduce = range`.] Now that you see these, of course, you notice it involves only the 3-way-interaction coefficients, so in fact any two linearly independent combinations of just the 12th and 13th coefficients will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to do this, to get *all* the hypothesis-testing contrasts, and that is to use the `joint_tests()` function:

```
> jt <- joint_tests(model)
> jt
 model term                 df1 df2 F.ratio p.value
 Sex                          1 107   0.756  0.3865
 Group                        2 107   2.190  0.1169
 TimeFromBaseline             1 107   0.083  0.7741
 Extra                        1 107   4.466  0.0369
 Sex:Group                    2 107   0.908  0.4065
 Sex:TimeFromBaseline         1 107   0.055  0.8142
 Group:TimeFromBaseline       2 107   0.512  0.6009
 Sex:Group:TimeFromBaseline   2 107   4.469  0.0137
```

The `jt` object is *not* en `emmGrid`; it's just an extension of a data frame. But the needed information is in an attribute called `est.fcns` for "estimable functions":

```
> attr(jt, "est.fcns")
$Sex
     (Intercept)       SexF GroupB GroupC TimeFromBaseline ExtraBar SexF:GroupB
[1,]           0 -0.5258791      0      0                0        0   -0.175293
     SexF:GroupC SexF:TimeFromBaseline GroupB:TimeFromBaseline GroupC:TimeFromBaseline
[1,]   -0.175293            -0.7359572                       0                       0
     SexF:GroupB:TimeFromBaseline SexF:GroupC:TimeFromBaseline
[1,]                   -0.2453191                   -0.2453191

$Group
     (Intercept) SexF     GroupB     GroupC TimeFromBaseline ExtraBar SexF:GroupB
[1,]           0    0 -0.5200032  0.0000000                0        0  -0.2600016
[2,]           0    0  0.0000000 -0.5200032                0        0   0.0000000
     SexF:GroupC SexF:TimeFromBaseline GroupB:TimeFromBaseline GroupC:TimeFromBaseline
[1,]   0.0000000                     0              -0.7277339               0.0000000
[2,]  -0.2600016                     0               0.0000000              -0.7277339
     SexF:GroupB:TimeFromBaseline SexF:GroupC:TimeFromBaseline
[1,]                    -0.363867                     0.000000
[2,]                     0.000000                    -0.363867

$TimeFromBaseline
     (Intercept) SexF GroupB GroupC TimeFromBaseline ExtraBar SexF:GroupB SexF:GroupC
[1,]           0    0      0      0       -0.8090398        0           0           0
     SexF:TimeFromBaseline GroupB:TimeFromBaseline GroupC:TimeFromBaseline
[1,]            -0.4045199              -0.2696799              -0.2696799
     SexF:GroupB:TimeFromBaseline SexF:GroupC:TimeFromBaseline
[1,]                     -0.13484                     -0.13484

$Extra
     (Intercept) SexF GroupB GroupC TimeFromBaseline ExtraBar SexF:GroupB SexF:GroupC
[1,]           0    0      0      0                0       -1           0           0
     SexF:TimeFromBaseline GroupB:TimeFromBaseline GroupC:TimeFromBaseline
[1,]                     0                       0                       0
     SexF:GroupB:TimeFromBaseline SexF:GroupC:TimeFromBaseline
[1,]                            0                            0

$`Sex:Group`
     (Intercept) SexF GroupB GroupC TimeFromBaseline ExtraBar SexF:GroupB SexF:GroupC
[1,]           0    0      0      0                0        0  -0.5813813   0.0000000
[2,]           0    0      0      0                0        0   0.0000000  -0.5813813
     SexF:TimeFromBaseline GroupB:TimeFromBaseline GroupC:TimeFromBaseline
[1,]                     0                       0                       0
[2,]                     0                       0                       0
     SexF:GroupB:TimeFromBaseline SexF:GroupC:TimeFromBaseline
[1,]                   -0.8136313                    0.0000000
[2,]                    0.0000000                   -0.8136313

$`Sex:TimeFromBaseline`
     (Intercept) SexF GroupB GroupC TimeFromBaseline ExtraBar SexF:GroupB SexF:GroupC
[1,]           0    0      0      0                0        0           0           0
     SexF:TimeFromBaseline GroupB:TimeFromBaseline GroupC:TimeFromBaseline
[1,]             -0.904534                       0                       0
     SexF:GroupB:TimeFromBaseline SexF:GroupC:TimeFromBaseline
[1,]                   -0.3015113                   -0.3015113

$`Group:TimeFromBaseline`
     (Intercept) SexF GroupB GroupC TimeFromBaseline ExtraBar SexF:GroupB SexF:GroupC
[1,]           0    0      0      0                0        0           0           0
[2,]           0    0      0      0                0        0           0           0
     SexF:TimeFromBaseline GroupB:TimeFromBaseline GroupC:TimeFromBaseline
[1,]                     0              -0.8944272               0.0000000
[2,]                     0               0.0000000              -0.8944272
     SexF:GroupB:TimeFromBaseline SexF:GroupC:TimeFromBaseline
[1,]                   -0.4472136                    0.0000000
[2,]                    0.0000000                   -0.4472136

$`Sex:Group:TimeFromBaseline`
     (Intercept) SexF GroupB GroupC TimeFromBaseline ExtraBar SexF:GroupB SexF:GroupC
[1,]           0    0      0      0                0        0           0           0
[2,]           0    0      0      0                0        0           0           0
     SexF:TimeFromBaseline GroupB:TimeFromBaseline GroupC:TimeFromBaseline
[1,]                     0                       0                       0
[2,]                     0                       0                       0
     SexF:GroupB:TimeFromBaseline SexF:GroupC:TimeFromBaseline
[1,]                           -1                            0
[2,]                            0                           -1
```